# Requirejs optimizer

Tags: javascript, optimization, requirejs, requirejs-optimizer

Is there a way to handle errors that occur during optimisation. 
For example, If there is an error in a javascript file, the file should be included, but it should not be optimised . and is there an option to generate a log for the errors.

My build.js

```
({
    appDir: __dirname,
    baseUrl: "/",
    dir: "production-build",
    optimize: 'uglify2',
    optimizeCss: 'standard',
    removeCombined: true,
    preserveLicenseComments: false
})
```

Comment: This is not possible. Why would you want errors in your build files?!

Comment: I don't want errors in my build file, I am asking, Is there a way to check any files in my project has errors while building, If there is an error in my js file, It should stop or log it  @Ryan